# Running python in VS code such that I can test functions on the REPL

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a Python file in VS code. I have a very simple function that takes in a number and returns the sum of its digits. However, when I actually run the Python file on VS Code, it does nothing and does not open a REPL so I can manually test the function on n.

For example, I tried `python3` on the terminal, and it opened the REPL, but with none of the functions in the actual file I was working on. When I run it as usual, it just goes over the file and does nothing. Is there any way I can open a REPL with all the functions in my file available so that I will be able to test the function at different numbers while the repl is running? I know this may seem like a dumb question but it will be really useful to me.

Comment: In REPL, type "import myfile" (without the "" and replacing myfile with the actual name). I think it's without the file extension, but not sure about that (you'll find out from the exception if it's wrong).

Comment: I still get a NameError for the function, it says it doesn't exist

Comment: you can use [Python Interactive](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click in the code editor window and select `Run Current File in Interactive Window`, or select `Jupyter: Create Interactive Window` in the command palette to open an interactive window.

[image]

[image]

There is another way you can open the REPL and select the entire content of the script and use the shortcut key <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, or right-click to run the code in the REPL.

[image]

[image]